# On submit ajax with confirm dialog not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Please see below script:

```
function is_holiday()
   {
       var start = $("#datepicker").val(),
       end = $("#datepicker1").val();
       var dateAr = start.split('/');
       var start_date = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0];
       var dateAr2 = end.split('/');
       var end_date = dateAr2[2] + '-' + dateAr2[1] + '-' + dateAr2[0];
       var confirm_data = 0;
       var holiday_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>userappointments/multiday/'+start_date+'/'+end_date;
       $.ajax
       ({
            type: "POST",
            url: holiday_url,
            success: function(result)
            {
               if(result != '')
               {  
                  window.confirm(result + "Are you sure you want to proceed?");
               }
            }
       });
    }
```

And form code is below

```
<form onsubmit="return is_holiday();"  method="post" id="form1" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>userappointments/newappointment/<?php if(isset($app_cus)) { echo '?customer_id='.$app_cus;} ?>">
```

When we submit form is submitted but ajax does not call with Confirm dialog. We want when we submit that time it first goes to in ajax then if it got result it should display confirm box and then when click on Ok. then form is submitted.

Comment: Have you looked at `beforeSend` for AJAX calls? What you're doing at the moment is firing the call, without performing your check so no matter if the string is empty, the user is always proceeding. `beforeSend` will allow you to do your `confirm` before the call is sent http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can you provide me some more information? we are not getting exactly.

Comment: Check the link in my comment

Comment: How we use this function?

Comment: Check out my answer, that might help you. `beforeSend1` probably won't work how you'd like, i misunderstood your intentions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`confirm(result + "Are you sure you want to proceed?");`

instead of

`window.confirm(result + "Are you sure you want to proceed?");`

EDIT - try this:

```
function is_holiday(){
   var start = $("#datepicker").val(),
   end = $("#datepicker1").val();
   var dateAr = start.split('/');
   var start_date = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0];
   var dateAr2 = end.split('/');
   var end_date = dateAr2[2] + '-' + dateAr2[1] + '-' + dateAr2[0];
   var confirm_data = 0;
   var holiday_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>userappointments/multiday/'+start_date+'/'+end_date;
   $.ajax
   ({
        type: "POST",
        url: holiday_url,
        success: function(result)
        {
           if(result != '')
           {  
              if(confirm(result + "Are you sure you want to proceed?")){
                // If it's confirmed, do stuff here
                alert('Confirmed');
              }
              return false;
           }
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: When we add return false after function end it will works. but when we click on Ok. Its not proceed process.

Comment: define *not working* Did i put the return false in the right place to where you put it?

Comment: I've added an alert to the confirm, can you please let me know what part doesn't work

Comment: Please add the updated script above (with the alert) and let me know, then i'll check it out

Comment: No you haven't i have updated the code above with an alert inside the confirm. PLEASE add this updated code to your website, i can see it doesn't have the alert inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57816/discussion-between-andy-holmes-and-kruti).